# How can I generate a map offscreen then render to an image

Tags: ios, mapkit

I want to find a way, in iOS SDK, to generate a map with an overlay offscreen and then generate a UIImage with it in order to generate an email compose screen with the map.

I've tried taking an on screen mapview and generating the overlay and then capturing the image but that doesn't work, it seems to grab the map before the overlay is applied, so I the map doesn't re-draw with the overlay until the view is told to redraw.

I also tried creating a mapview just in code and capturing that but all I got was a blank map, again I dont think it renders before I capture its image.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it still actual? Can you post your code here?

Comment: I couldn't find a fix so I decided to generate the map image with a call to Google Maps

Comment: I have exactly this problem right now. Anyone?